# Find closing anchor tag after image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I would like to move a div to the spot right after a closing anchor tag.  All I have been given is the image classname.  How do I find the closing anchor tag wrapping the image?

```
<a href="#"><img class="cat-image" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" title="Funky roots" /></a>
```

On JS Fiddle I have an example where I iterate through a list looking for an image with a certain class name.  If that image exists I would like to move the `'.moveMe'` to after the closing anchor tag.

Unfortunately I can't modify the html.  I can't add an id or class to the anchor or image tags or wrap the whole thing in a div.

HTML:

```
<ul class='testList'>
    <li class="listItem-0">
        <div class="moveMe"></div> <pre>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="#"><img class="cat-image" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" title="Funky roots" /></a><!-- moveMe div here -->
        </div>
        <div class="summary"></div>
        </pre>

    </li>
    <li class="listItem-1">
        <div class="moveMe"></div>  <pre>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="summary"></div>
        </pre>

    </li>
    <li class="listItem-2">
        <div class="moveMe"></div>  <pre>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="#"><img class="cat-image" src="http://placekitten.com/300/400" title="bigger cat pic" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="summary"></div>
        </pre>

    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var listItems = $(".testList li");

listItems.each(function (idx, li) {
    if ($(li).find('.cat-image').length) {
        console.log('listItemContent image==>', $('pre').find('.cat-image'));  
        /*$(li).find('???? </a>  ????').append($(li).find('.moveMe'));*/
    }
    console.log($('.testList').html());
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBTNU/2/)

Comment: You can use closest('a')

Comment: Move which `div`? Or did you mean to create a new one?

Comment: So what's the problem? You can accomplish this with a rudimentary knowledge of jQuery or DOM manipulation in general.

Comment: @cookiemonster this site is designed to help people improve their "rudimentary knowledge" - judging by the OP's fiddle he has a basic understanding of jQuery already but perhaps not finer points and I assume that why he's asked a question.

Comment: @scrowler: I see no attempt at a solution in the question, so I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: There's an attempt in the fiddle, give him a break

Comment: @scrowler: What sort of a break were you hoping for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) in this context,

```
var listItems = $(".testList li");
var cache = null;

listItems.each(function (idx, li) {
    cache = $(li).find('.cat-image');
    if (cache.length) {
      cache.parent().after($(li).find('.moveMe'));
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MBTNU/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
var listItems = $(".testList li");
listItems.each(function (idx, li) {
    var jli = $(li);
    jli.find(".cat-image")
       .closest("a")
       .after(jli.find(".moveMe"));
});
```

which, if you like, can be reduced to a single line:

```
var listItems = $(".testList li");
listItems.each(function (idx, li) {
    $(li).find(".cat-image").closest("a").after($(li).find(".moveMe"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MBTNU/5/

Comment: Sorry to ask this but is declaring a variable inside a loop a good practice..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy It isn't a loop. It's an anonymous function. So no, I would say there's no problem here.

Comment: `each()` explicitly loops over the elements returned by the selector; so yes: it's a loop. While that's not necessarily a problem it does introduce a *slight * inefficiency/performance penalty. And given you're only using the cached selector/jQuery object once there's no need to initialise a variable anyway.

Comment: @DavidThomas It's being used twice. That's why I used a variable.